# Issue with VBScript to detect when a usb is inserted and check if it's encrypted

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, usb, encryption, vbscript

I'm trying to write a vbscript that can be pushed through Kace K1000 and run in the background on the machines that we have in our network to detect whenever a user plug in their flash drive/external drive and check if they're encrypted.

If drive is not encrypted, send a prompt/message telling the user to encrypt the drive. If the drive is already encrypted, do nothing, proceed as normal. The OS I'm working with is Windows 7 and 10.

The script I have so far is:

```
    strComputer = "." 

//check instant event for usb detection

    Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set wmiEvent = wmi.ExecNotificationQuery("select * from __InstanceOperationEvent within 1 where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity' and TargetInstance.Description='USB Mass Storage Device'")

//check to see if the drive is encrypted 

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption") 
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume",,48) 

    While True

    Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"  

    For Each objItem in colItems 

    If objItem.ProtectionStatus = 0 then

    Wscript.Echo "Unencrypted drive is detected, please encrypt drive " & objItem.DriveLetter

    else 
        end if 
    Next
    Wend
```

I understand it's not working at the moment and I'm very new to vbscript and wmi so any help would be great. I got the script so far through googling before deciding to ask for help.

If you guys have any other way to go about what I'm trying to do, that would also be great. We use kace k1000 to manage our machines so I need to be able to push the script through there.

Thank you

Comment: We're doing more or less the same thing but using BitLocker and Group Policy, no running scripts necessary. It requires the drive be encrypted before you can write any files to it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679890(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_driveaccess2

Comment: that's one way to approach it but AD group policy is managed by our corporate team which I don't have access right to mess with. That's why I'm resorting to script and kace k1000 to push it out. Thanks though

Comment: Ah, yea that would be troublesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following (partially commented) script works in Windows environment and I can't foresee *kace k1000* interaction:

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strResult, strComputer, wmi, wmiEvent , objWMIService, objItem, colItems, objEventObject
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer _
  & "\ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption")       ' requires elevation
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
' //check instant event for Logical Disk detection
Set wmiEvent = wmi.ExecNotificationQuery( _
    "select * from __InstanceOperationEvent within 1 " _
  & "where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk'")
While True
    ''  tell the script to wait until the next event of interest occurs
    Set objEventObject = wmiEvent.NextEvent()
    Select Case objEventObject.Path_.Class
        Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
          '//check to see if the drive is encrypted 
          Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
              "SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume",,48) 
          For Each objItem in colItems 
            If objItem.ProtectionStatus = 0 then
              strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & ":" & _
                objEventObject.TargetInstance.Description & _
                  ": Unencrypted drive " & objItem.DriveLetter
            End If 
          Next
        Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent"     '' merely for debugging
          strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & ":" & _
            objEventObject.TargetInstance.Description & ": An event was just deleted" 
    End Select
    If strResult <> "" Then Wscript.Echo Wscript.ScriptName & vbNewLine & strResult
    strResult = ""
 Wend

'' REMARK ''
'' //check instant event for usb detection
'' -- unsuccessful as `TargetInstance.Description` could vary for different drives
' Set wmiEvent = wmi.ExecNotificationQuery( _
'     "select * from __InstanceOperationEvent within 1 " _
'   & "where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'" _
'   & " and ( TargetInstance.Description='USB Mass Storage Device'" _
'   & "    or TargetInstance.Description='USB Flash Memory'" _ 
'   & "    or TargetInstance.Description='Disk drive')")
```

Here's an exhaustive explanation: [How Can I Monitor for Different Types of Events With Just One Script](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/04/04/how-can-i-monitor-for-different-types-of-events-with-just-one-script/) and [How Can I Determine When a Removable Drive Gets Connected](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/02/13/how-can-i-determine-when-a-removable-drive-gets-connected/)

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps me immensely. Not sure how I didn't find those pages when googling.